# installing mysqlclient with python3

Tags: mysql, pip, python-3.5

I want to install `mysqlclient` and using it with python3 so just type in command line:

```
$ sudo -H pip3 install mysqlclient
Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
```

and then

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import mysqlclient
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'mysqlclient'
```

What is wrong here?

**Note**: libmysqlclient-dev it's already installed with most recent version (5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:
`import MySQLdb`

mysqlclient is actually a port for mysqldb to Python 3.x. They changed the name of the lib so it won't conflict with the original one.